# Document sheet not responding to keyboard events

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindow, nsapplication

I think it's a first responder problem, but I'm not sure.  I'm implementing an edit window for data in a table view.  Very similar in concept to the UI for editing filter rules in Mail.app.

I have an editing window that I attach to my primary window with:

```
[NSApp beginSheet: criteriaEditPanel 
   modalForWindow: [self window] 
    modalDelegate: self 
   didEndSelector: @selector(criteriaEditDidEnd:returnCode:contextInfo:) 
      contextInfo: (void *)[criteriaList objectAtIndex: index]];
```

The panel displays properly, from the title bar of the main window.  I can manipulate the pop-up controls on the panel with the mouse, but I can't edit the text fields and I can't tab between fields.  Everything else works fine.  Any ideas?

joe

Comment: Still no success on this.  Adding comment in hopes of the night crowd seeing it.  Thanks.

Comment: Do you override anything to do with responder?

Comment: No, not that I can think of.  But I've done a lot of tweaking of xib file settings that I wonder if I messed up something there.

Comment: Probably. Try unchecking anything that says ***Refuse first responder***.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Solved.  Believe it or not, you have to have the Title Bar enabled for the panel, even though it's never visible when displayed as a Sheet.  When enabled it in IB, keyboard input started working.

@spudwaffle - none of the objects had ***Refuse First Responder*** checked.

Comment: I understand this to mean that the style mask of the sheet window (not the parent window) must include NSTitledWindowMask, or check the IB box "Title Bar." Also, I saw this issue in a non-document app, using the new (10.9) NSWindow sheet API.

Comment: That's correct, Paul.  The panel you're using as the sheet, not the parent.

Comment: PLEASE COPY THIS ANSWER SOMEWHERE!

Comment: @MarekH Other than here?  Why?

Comment: Took me few searches till this one showed. I was looking for "first resonder incorrect modal window". My first responder was the window that showed the modal, not the modal itself.

Comment: Confirmed here in a document-based 10.9 NSWindow sheet API app; this is still an issue at least as late as macOS 10.13.4. (and, yes, future person, we did all think we were so modern back in 2018)

Comment: Saved me a lot of time. Title Bar must be enabled on sheets. Works on other sheets too (not only Document).

Comment: @Tommy: You'll be happy to know that here in the amazing future that is 2021, this is still an issue in macOS 11.1 Big Sur! (And don't worry about the next few years, you won't believe how great things are going in 2020 and 2021.)