# Displaying a progress indicator sheet on NSDocument shows up greyed out (though still serves purpose)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdocument

### **First Try - beginSheet: completionHandler: Method**

I have a document-based application that does moderately intense saving (approximately 10-15 seconds, but definitely noticeable).  In order for the end-user to not think that the app is hung up, I've added a progress indicator that is displayed as a sheet over the document.  I'm able to display my progress indicator as a sheet while the document is being saved, and the sheet properly disappears when the save is over.  However, the indicator is greyed out.  I know this is more of an aesthetic problem but would appreciate pointers on how to remedy this.

Below is a screenshot of the progress indicator.  Instead of the blue and animated bar, it is greyed out and still.

[image]

I've listed the relevant code below.

**Code to display progress indicator:**

```
- (void) showProgressIndicatorSheet
{
    NSStoryboard *storyboard = [NSStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    modalProgressWindowController = [storyboard instantiateControllerWithIdentifier:@"modalProgressWindowController"];

    NSArray *windowControllers = self.windowControllers;
    if ([windowControllers count] > 0) {
        NSWindowController *controller = windowControllers[0];
        [controller.window beginSheet:modalProgressWindowController.window completionHandler:nil];
    }
}
```

**Code to hide sheet:**

```
- (void) hideProgressIndicatorSheet
{
    if (modalProgressWindowController) {
        NSArray *windowControllers = self.windowControllers;
        if ([windowControllers count] > 0) {
            NSWindowController *controller = windowControllers[0];
            [controller.window endSheet:modalProgressWindowController.window];
        }
    }
}
```

**Code that display the indicator then hides it while saving:**

```
- (BOOL)writeToURL:(NSURL *)url ofType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError * _Nullable __autoreleasing *)outError {
    [self showProgressIndicatorSheet];

    /* code to save data to file */

    [self hideProgressIndicatorSheet];
}
```

---

### **Second Try - beginModalSessionForWindow: Method**

As was alluded to by a comment that maybe using a window sheet is the issue here. I did some searching around and found `beginModalSessionForWindow` and it's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplication/1428590-runmodalsession?language=objc).  Looked promising so I tried using it but have the same problem where the progress bar is greyed out.  I also have a new problem where I cannot stop the modal despite calling `[NSApp stopModal]`.

**Code to display progress indicator:**

```
- (void) showProgressIndicatorSheet
{
    NSStoryboard *storyboard = [NSStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    modalProgressWindowController = [storyboard instantiateControllerWithIdentifier:@"modalProgressWindowController"];

    session = [NSApp beginModalSessionForWindow:modalProgressWindowController.window];
}
```

**Code to dismiss modal:**

```
- (void) hideProgressIndicatorSheet
{
    [NSApp endModalSession:session];
}
```

**Code that display the indicator then dismisses it while saving:**

```
- (BOOL)writeToURL:(NSURL *)url ofType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError * _Nullable __autoreleasing *)outError {
    [self showProgressIndicatorSheet];

    BOOL response = NO;
    BOOL beganSave = NO;

    while ([NSApp runModalSession:session] == NSModalResponseContinue) {
        if (!beganSave) {
            beganSave = YES;
            response = [self saveToDBForURL:url];
        }
    }

    [self hideProgressIndicatorSheet];

    return response;
}
```

**stopModal inside of saveToDBForURL:**

```
- (BOOL)saveTODBForURL: (NSURL *) url {

    /* save method */

    // stop modal after saving is done
    [NSApp stopModal];

    // return whether save was success or not...
    return response;
}
```

Comment: I think that's because you are using a window sheet.

Comment: @ElTomato I think you're right.  I found `[NSApp runModalSessionForWindow:(NSWindow *)window]` which looks promising. But I need to figure out how to get the save to happen while the modal occurs.  Will do more research in a bit.  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplication/1428590-runmodalsession?language=objc

Comment: Update: So I tried `runModalSessionForWindow` and followed Apple's documentations but now have two problems: (1) the same issue where the progress bar is greyed out, and (2) I can't seem to get the modal to disappear after saving...it lingers despite calling `[NSApp stopModal]` and breaking from loop `if ([NSApp runModalSession:session] != NSModalResponseContinue])`.  I feel like I'm missing something straight forward.

Comment: Try `beginSheet`, `beginModalSessionForWindow`, `runModalSession`, save, `endModalSession`, `endSheet`.

Comment: @Willeke, thanks for the suggestion but I still get a greyed out progress bar.  I'm starting to wonder if I'm invoking the code to start a sheet in the wrong place...  I've noticed if I run a sheet from the VC then I get a properly animated progress window. It's only when I call it from my Document class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved!  Willeke is correct about invoking all the methods in the comment.  But that alone was not enough...I was still getting the greyed out progress bar.  I stumbled on the following post on SO ["Document sheet not responding to keyboard events"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7122696/document-sheet-not-responding-to-keyboard-events).  Turns out, *you must have "**title bar" enabled** in IB!*

With the title bar enabled in IB, here is the updated code that works (hopefully no one else will need to run into this weirdness!):

**Code to display sheet**

```
- (void) showProgressIndicatorSheet
{
    NSArray *windowControllers = self.windowControllers;
    if ([windowControllers count] > 0) {
        NSWindowController *controller = windowControllers[0];
        ((BWProgressIndicatorSheetViewController *)modalProgressWindowController.window.contentViewController).progressLabel.stringValue = @"Saving workspace...";
        [controller.window beginSheet:modalProgressWindowController.window completionHandler:nil];
        session = [NSApp beginModalSessionForWindow:modalProgressWindowController.window];
    }
}
```

**Code to dismiss sheet**

```
- (void) hideProgressIndicatorSheet
{
    [NSApp endModalSession:session];
    if (modalProgressWindowController) {
        NSArray *windowControllers = self.windowControllers;
        if ([windowControllers count] > 0) {
            NSWindowController *controller = windowControllers[0];
            [controller.window endSheet:modalProgressWindowController.window];
        }
    }
}
```

**Code that display the indicator then dismisses it while saving**

```
- (BOOL)writeToURL:(NSURL *)url ofType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError * _Nullable __autoreleasing *)outError {

    [self showProgressIndicatorSheet];

    BOOL response = NO;
    BOOL beganSave = NO;

    while ([NSApp runModalSession:session] == NSModalResponseContinue) {
        if (!beganSave) {
            beganSave = YES;
            response = [self saveToDBForURL:url];
        }
    }

    [self hideProgressIndicatorSheet];

    return response;
}
```

**And lastly...stopModal inside of saveToDBForURL:**

```
- (BOOL) saveToDBForURL: (NSURL *) url
{
    // do saving here

    [NSApp stopModal];

    return response;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I had turned off the title bar in IB so my sheet would appear like a sheet, but then I couldn't figure out why I wasn't able to interact with it. I could still click on the parent window behind the sheet (an NSDocument) but nothing on the sheet was working.